# How does C++ union know the type stored in it and which destructor to call?

Tags: c++, unions

Working with a `union` of two classes, it appears in this simple example that the `union` remembers the last class stored in it and calls the correct destructor for that object:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct yes{
    yes(){cout<<"yes-c"<<endl;}
    ~yes(){cout<<"yes-d"<<endl;}
};
struct no{
    no(){cout<<"no-c"<<endl;}
    ~no(){cout<<"no-d"<<endl;}
};
struct u{
    union{
        yes y;
        no n;
    };
    u(yes _y):y(_y){}
    u(no _n):n(_n){}        
    ~u(){}
};


int main() {
    yes y;
    no n;
    {
    u uu(n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
yes-c
no-c
no-d
no-d
yes-d
```

So the `uu` will call the correct destructor `~no()` for the union, as if it records the type when the union is constructed. How does this work?

Comment: I've fixed your code here, but next time please post the full code of your program (and relevant output).

Comment: @melpomene thank you. I did try to post the full code but the website told me I have too much code so I have to cut it out to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: It doesn't.

If you add a copy-constructor to `no` you will see that there are actually *three* `no` objects being created, but only two are destructed.

First you create the object `n`. Then when you pass it *by value* to the `u` constructor, it is copied once into the `_n` argument. That `_n` object is then copied into the `uu.n` member.

The destructions are of the `_n` argument in the `u` constructor, and the `n` object in the `main` function.

---

Here's your program with some slight modification to add the copy-constructor and to keep track of the `no` objects:

```
#include <iostream>

struct yes{
    yes(){std::cout<<"yes-c"<<std::endl;}
    ~yes(){std::cout<<"yes-d"<<std::endl;}
};
struct no{
    no(){std::cout<<"no-c : "<<n<<std::endl;}
    no(no const& o)
        : n(o.n + 1)
    {
        std::cout << "no-cc : " << o.n << " -> " << n << '\n';
    }

    ~no(){std::cout<<"no-d : "<<n<<std::endl;}
    int n = 0;
};
struct u{
    union{
        yes y;
        no n;
    };
    u(yes _y):y(_y){}
    u(no _n):n(_n){}
    ~u(){}
};

int main()
{
    yes y;
    no n;
    {
        u uu(n);
    }
}
```

Without optimizations or copy-elision this will create the output

```
yes-c
no-c : 0
no-cc : 0 -> 1
no-cc : 1 -> 2
no-d : 1
no-d : 0
yes-d
```

The output `no-c : 0` is for the creation of the `n` object in the `main` function.

The output `no-cc : 0 -> 1` is for the copying into the `u` constructor argument `_n`.

The output `no-cc : 1 -> 2` is for the copying of the argument `_n` into the unions `n` object.

The output `no-d : 1` is the destruction of the `_n` argument.

The output `no-d : 0` is the destruction of the `n` object in the `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

`union`s never "remember" which field is active.

Your code outputs:

> ```
> yes-c
> no-c
> no-d
> no-d
> yes-d
> ```

You seem to interpret the 3rd line (`no-d`) as a destructor call for a union field of your class, but that's not what happens here. `~u()` isn't going to call destructors for `y` nor `n`.

You pass parameters to your constructors by value, thus this line is a destructor call for the parameter of the constructor.

Comment: Indeed!  Here the code with 3 output that allow to easily realise the issue: https://ideone.com/M1ZBXp But what to advise to get it done correctly ?

Comment: @Christophe As WhiZTiM suggested, `std::variant`.

Answer (score 2):

No, a [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) doesn't "know" it's active member. We have [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for that job. What you see is the result of the temporary created in the constructor for your `union`.

When making a union of non-trivial types. You are very likely to fall into traps of invoking Undefined Behavior as your program gets more complex; `std::variant` does a good job tagging your union.. And it will manage lifetimes appropriately

Answer (score 0):

A `union` will be large enough to hold the largest variable declared within the `union` so that an object of any of the variable types declared in the `union` can be stored there.

However what is stored within the `union` is not tracked. Any object stored in a `union` must be explicitly destroyed as a part of destroying the object containing the `union` just as any object stored in a `union` much be explicitly constructed as a part of constructing the object containing the `union`.

It is up to the programmer to have some mechanism to track what, if anything, is stored in the `union` and to properly handle any construction and destruction actions.

It is up to the programmer to properly access what is stored within a `union` by knowing what is stored in the `union` and then using the appropriate `union` member to access that object.

**Program demonstrating using a `union`**

Starting with the source from other answers, I expanded that source to demonstrate the difference between a `union` member of a `struct` and a `struct` member of a `struct`.

In the code below I have for the `union` containing class `u` constructors for both the `yes` class and the `no` class. In addition I have a default constructor, copy constructor, and an assignment operator for the class `u`.

In addition to the two structs you provided, `yes` and `no`, I have also provided a third `struct`, `place`, which is not used in the `union` but is instead just another member variable.

Each of the various classes/structs have a static counter to count up each time one is constructed.

I have provided the assignment operator for the `struct` of `u` in order to properly handle the assignment. The default assignment operator amounted to a bitwise copy and I wanted to preserve the unique identifier for each instance in order for the tracking of construction and destruction to be properly documented.

**`union` vs `struct` and containing object construction/destruction**

Notice that in the output generated by this program, when the `class` containing the `union` is constructed, the `place` struct is constructed however none of the `union` members are constructed. And when the `class` containing the `union` is destructed, the `place` struct is destructed however none of the `union` members are destructed.

You can also see in the output where temporary variables are constructed, used, and then destructed. However notice that when a temporary is assigned into the `union`, the destructor is never called.

So in the program there is this simple scope with a couple of statements.

```
{
    std::cout << "scope in" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  create uu from n" << std::endl;
    u uu(n);
    std::cout << "  assign y to uu" << std::endl;
    uu = y;
    std::cout << "  assign n to uu" << std::endl;
    uu = n;
    std::cout << "scope out" << std::endl;
}
```

And the section of output which I have annotated with a few notes corresponding to this section of source is:

```
scope in
  create uu from n
   no-cc : 0 -> 1                        ---  create a temporary struct no for the call to construct
   no-cc : 1 -> 2                        --- assignment of temporary to union through copy construction
   place-c : 1                           --- construct non-union struct member
 u-c - no: 1 place 1  tu: 2  tu_no: 2
   no-d : 1                               --- destruct the temporary passed to the constructor
  assign y to uu
   yes-cc : 0 -> 1                        ---  create a temporary struct yes for the assignment
   yes-cc : 1 -> 2                        --- assignment of temporary to union through copy construction
   place-c : 2                            --- construct non-union struct member
 u-c - yes: 2 place 2  tu: 1  tu_yes: 2   --- construct temporary union member using yes version of the constructors
   yes-d: 1                               --- destruct the temporary used in assignment
 u-= : 2 into 1 o.place 2  tu: 1  tu_yes: 2
 u-d : 2  tu: 1  tu_yes: 2                --- destruct temporary union struct
   place-d : 2                            --- destruct non-union struct member
  assign n to uu
   no-cc : 0 -> 3                        ---  create a temporary struct no for the assignment
   no-cc : 3 -> 4                       --- assignment of temporary to union through copy construction
   place-c : 3
 u-c - no: 3 place 3  tu: 2  tu_no: 4   --- construct temporary union using no version of constructors
   no-d : 3                             --- destruct the struct no temporary
u-= : 3 into 1 o.place 3  tu: 2  tu_no: 4
 u-d : 3  tu: 2  tu_no: 4               --- destruct the struct union temporary
   place-d : 3
scope out
```

followed by the destruction of the instance of `u` created within the scope as the variable goes out of scope with:

```
 u-d : 1  tu: 2  tu_no: 2
   place-d : 1
```

Notice that we have an instance of `no`, instance identifier 2, and an instance of `yes`, instance identifier 2, that we never see a destructor message. These are the temporaries actually stored into the `union`. Notice that every instance of the member `place` is destructed as its container of `u` is destructed.

**Source code and output for `union` example**

The source code for this demo program:

```
// union_test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723339/how-does-c-union-know-the-type-stored-in-it-and-which-destructor-to-call

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

struct yes {
    yes() : n(nc++) { std::cout << "   yes-c: " << n << std::endl; }
    yes(yes const& o) : n(nc++)
    {
        std::cout << "   yes-cc : " << o.n << " -> " << n << '\n';
    }
    ~yes() { std::cout << "   yes-d: " << n << std::endl; }
    int n = 0;        // identifier number for specific instance
    static int nc;    // count of number of instances of this class created, instance identifier
};

struct no {
    no() : n(nc++) { std::cout << "   no-c : " << n << std::endl; }
    no(no const& o) : n(nc++)
    {
        std::cout << "   no-cc : " << o.n << " -> " << n << '\n';
    }

    ~no() { std::cout << "   no-d : " << n << std::endl; }
    int n = 0;        // identifier number for specific instance
    static int nc;    // count of number of instances of this class created, instance identifier
};

struct place {
    place() : n(nc++) { std::cout << "   place-c : " << n << std::endl; }
    place(no const& o) : n(nc++)
    {
        std::cout << "   place-cc : " << o.n << " -> " << n << '\n';
    }

    ~place() { std::cout << "   place-d : " << n << std::endl; }
    int n = 0;        // identifier number for specific instance
    static int nc;    // count of number of instances of this class created, instance identifier
};
struct u {
    union {
        yes y;
        no n;
    };
    place p;          // non-union to see construction/destruction of non-union.
    int nu = 0;       // identifier number for specific instance
    int tu = 0;       // indicator as to type currently in the union
    static int nc;    // count of number of instances of this class created, instance identifier
    u() : nu(nc++) { std::cout << " u-c : " << nu << " place " << p.n << "  tu: " << tu << std::endl; }
    u(yes _y) :y(_y), nu(nc++), tu(1) {
        std::cout << " u-c - yes: " << nu << " place " << p.n << "  tu: " << tu;
        switch (tu) {
        case 0:
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "  tu_yes: " << y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "  tu_no: " << y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown  tu: " << tu << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    u(no _n) :n(_n), nu(nc++), tu(2) {
        std::cout << " u-c - no: " << nu << " place " << p.n << "  tu: " << tu;
        switch (tu) {
        case 0:
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "  tu_yes: " << y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "  tu_no: " << y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown  tu: " << tu << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    u(u const& o) : nu(nc++), tu(o.tu)
    {
        std::cout << "u-cc : " << o.nu << " -> " << nu << "  tu: " << tu << " o.place " << o.p.n;
        switch (tu) {
        case 0:
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "  tu_yes: " << o.y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "  tu_no: " << o.n.n << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown  tu: " << tu << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    u & operator = (const u & o)
    {
        std::cout << "u-= : " << o.nu << " into " << nu << " o.place " << o.p.n << "  tu: " << o.tu;
        tu = o.tu;
        switch (o.tu) {
        case 0:
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "  tu_yes: " << o.y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "  tu_no: " << o.n.n << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown  tu: " << tu << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~u() {
        std::cout << " u-d : " << nu << "  tu: " << tu;
        switch (tu) {
        case 0:
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "  tu_yes: " << y.n << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "  tu_no: " << n.n << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
};

int yes::nc = 0;
int no::nc = 0;
int place::nc = 0;
int u::nc = 0;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "create uu" << std::endl;
    u  xx;
    std::cout << "create y" << std::endl;
    yes y;
    std::cout << "create n" << std::endl;
    no n;
    {
        std::cout << "scope in" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  create uu from n" << std::endl;
        u uu(n);
        std::cout << "  assign y to uu" << std::endl;
        uu = y;
        std::cout << "  assign n to uu" << std::endl;
        uu = n;
        std::cout << "scope out" << std::endl;
    }

    xx = y;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output generated by this program.

```
create uu
   place-c : 0
 u-c : 0 place 0  tu: 0
create y
   yes-c: 0
create n
   no-c : 0
scope in
  create uu from n
   no-cc : 0 -> 1
   no-cc : 1 -> 2
   place-c : 1
 u-c - no: 1 place 1  tu: 2  tu_no: 2
   no-d : 1
  assign y to uu
   yes-cc : 0 -> 1
   yes-cc : 1 -> 2
   place-c : 2
 u-c - yes: 2 place 2  tu: 1  tu_yes: 2
   yes-d: 1
u-= : 2 into 1 o.place 2  tu: 1  tu_yes: 2
 u-d : 2  tu: 1  tu_yes: 2
   place-d : 2
  assign n to uu
   no-cc : 0 -> 3
   no-cc : 3 -> 4
   place-c : 3
 u-c - no: 3 place 3  tu: 2  tu_no: 4
   no-d : 3
u-= : 3 into 1 o.place 3  tu: 2  tu_no: 4
 u-d : 3  tu: 2  tu_no: 4
   place-d : 3
scope out
 u-d : 1  tu: 2  tu_no: 2
   place-d : 1
   yes-cc : 0 -> 3
   yes-cc : 3 -> 4
   place-c : 4
 u-c - yes: 4 place 4  tu: 1  tu_yes: 4
   yes-d: 3
u-= : 4 into 0 o.place 4  tu: 1  tu_yes: 4
 u-d : 4  tu: 1  tu_yes: 4
   place-d : 4
   no-d : 0
   yes-d: 0
 u-d : 0  tu: 1  tu_yes: -858993460
   place-d : 0
```